# Use .pt file to analyze an image

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

I'm really new in AI, so sorry for the conception mistakes I can do. I do have a .pt file, and I want to use it to get some bounding boxes of a picture. What's the most simple way to do it? Something like:

```
import torch
model=torch.load('best.pt')
img=['foto.jpg']
results = model(img)
results.show()
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

using

```
Syntax – torch.utils.draw_bounding_boxes(image, box)

Parameter:

image: Tensor of shape (C x H x W) 
box: Bounding boxes size in (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax).
Return: Image Tensor of dtype uint8 with bounding boxes plotted.
```

```py
# Import the required libraries
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision.io import read_image
from torchvision.utils import draw_bounding_boxes

# read input image from your computer
img = read_image('a3.pt')

# bounding box are xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
box = [330, 190, 660, 355]
box = torch.tensor(box)
box = box.unsqueeze(0)

# draw bounding box and fill color
img = draw_bounding_boxes(img, box, width=5,
                        colors="green",
                        fill=True)

# transform this image to PIL image
img = torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()(img)

# display output
img.show()
```

Comment: But how do I calculate the bounding box? I would like the model to calculate them